# iPad endpointIOTimerExpired error when plugging in iPad to Windows 7

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, usb

I get an error similar to the one below about 5-10 seconds after plugging in an iPad into a Windows 7 laptop.  When I plug the same iPads into a WinXP laptop, I do not get the error.  I tried it on two iPads (iOS 5.0.1 on one and iOS 5.1.1 on the other) and they both showed the error on the Win7 machine.

The XP machine has iTunes 10.5.0.42 installed.

I tried both iTunes 10.6.3.25 and 10.5.0.142 (after first uninstalling 10.6.3.25) on the Win7 machine and the error was there with both versions of iTunes.  I don't have a copy of the 10.5.0.42 installer or I would try that on the Win7 machine.

<strike>I suspect that this error is causing connection problems with my monotouch code on the Win7 machine which uses the USB connection to talk to the iPad.  My code works fine on the XP machine.</strike>

REPHRASE: I suspect that this error is causing connection problems between my iPad running a Monotouch client which communicates over the USB to a server on the Win7 machine.  My server on the XP machine communicates over the USB to the iPad just fine.  The server code is the same on both the XP and Win7 machine.  However, the error shown below appears when none of my code (on any machine/device) is running at all, so it looks like it might be an OS/Driver sort of issue.

[image]

Note: The image above is taken from [here](http://pastebin.com/mak0j0Zp).  The cause of my error (plugging in the iPad) is different than that listed in this link, but the error message is substantially similar.

Comment: Can you define *my monotouch code** ? MonoTouch tools does not run on Windows. MonoTouch apps runs on devices.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, I can reproduce this by plugging my ipad 2 into a Win7 VM on my mac (with latest iTunes installed)

I guess it's a Win7 + iOS issue? Not really anything to do with MonoTouch?